# LIBSVM overfitting

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm, cross-validation

I trained two svms (LIBSVM) with 15451 samples after I did a 10-fold cross-validation and found the best parameter values for gamma and C (RBF kernel). In one svm I used just 1 feature and in the second an additional one (to see whether this additional is improving prediction). After CV I have am accuracy of 75 % (SVM with one feature) and 77 % (SVM with that additional one). After testing on another 15451 instances I have an accuracy of 70 % and 72 % respectively.

I know that this is called overfitting but is it significant here, since it is only a difference of 5 %.

What could I do to avoid overfitting?

Is it even good to use just one or two features and a relatively big training set?

Hope you can help me out.

Comment: Why do you think you're overfitting? Getting higher scores in CV settings than on actual training sets is quite normal.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics. stats.stackexchange.com may be more appropriate.

Comment: While learning how SVMs perform and how to use them, I often came across this belief that, if you have a higher accuracy in CV and a lower after testing, you are overfitting. This is way I think I have a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion about overfitting here.

In short, "overfitting" does NOT mean that your accuracy on fitting the training set is (disproportionately) higher than fitting a generic test set. Rather, this is the effect and not the cause.

"Overfitting" means that your model is trying too hard to fit the training set at any cost, and after picking up all the signal there is it is starting to fit noise. As a (very standard) example, imagine to generate data points coming from a straight line, but then add a little Gaussian noise: the points will be "roughly" on a line, but not exactly. You are overfitting when you try to find a curve that will go through each and every point (say for example a polynomial of grade 27) when all you really needed was a straight line.

One way to check this visually is to draw a learning curve.

This webpage looks informative so I would start here to know more: http://www.astroml.org/sklearn_tutorial/practical.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So this means that the model is not overfitting, since it is a common thing a model performs better on training set (because I also chosed the parameter values corresponding to the best accuracy) and is slightly worse by predicting test data...?

Comment: Maybe it is a bit out of topic...but when I am comparing two SVMs (with different number of features, but on the same data)...how can I be sure that one SVM (with an additional feature) is better than the other. Because if I increase the C parameter, I always get a better cross-val-accuracy for both SVMs...how can I know when to stop increasing C? If I say in a specific range of C, the second SVM is slightly better, I might be wrong, because there could be some calues of C beyond this range which could lead to a better performance of the initially worse SVM....you know what I mean?

Comment: I know what you mean :) The key here is realizing that machine learning has some intrinsic limitations, which are due to the fact that you want to learn from a finite amount of data a general rule that you want to apply just as well to a possibly infinite amount of data... Of course it's not going to work, at least not in the general case. The theory teaches you how to use what you have in the best way (for example, "always use a test set") and how to estimate how good you can do out of sample

Comment: So to answer your question about comparing two SVMs... You should have a test set over which you evaluate your models. Remember that the guiding principle here is that the more you use some data to make decisions, the more that dataset gets "dirty" and the higher your risk of overfitting is. If you have a single training set and a single test set and you want to try 99999 different values for C, then you have 99999 different models and you are using your test set to make decisions on them ("which one is best?"). This will most likely end up with you picking the best model FOR THAT SET

Comment: So in practice, you want to have two separate "test sets" and one training set. On the first "test set" (which we call "Validation set") you tune the parameters (prof. Yaser Abu-Mostafa suggests to have 100 examples for each parameter you want to estimate this way). Then, say you pick your 3 best models on your validation set and then you run them on the test set to elect a winner. Will this pick the very best model possible? Probably not, but it will make the most sensible decision given the amount of data you have